# Is there a way to have a div tag without having a line break, or is there an alternative?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, stylesheet

In my website, in asp.net 4 / vb, I have a situation where I need to include a class, "**noprint**", in my footer, as defined in **print.css**.  But I already have a span class, so I wrapped div tags around it.  And my tr's and td's all have classes in them already.

Basically, I have this in my footer:

**Knowledge Base | Contact USS | Copyright © USS Vision Inc. 2012 | 888-888-8888**

And the only thing I want printed out is the phone number.

I use

```
<div class="noprint">whatever I want omitted when printing</div>
```

And that works fine.  But when viewing the webpage, I don't want the `888-888-8888` to appear below everything else, so I can't use div tags, I suppose.  The noprint works great, but is there any way I can use the noprint in my footer without putting the phone number below the rest of the footer due to the div tags?  Thanks for any help anybody can offer!

Update:  My **print.css** stylesheet looks like this:

```
@media screen
{
   /* whatever styles you have for display */
}

@media print
{
   .noprint { display: none; }
}
```

So I don't know how to make the div tags `display: inline`, but I will search around and try to figure it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gd1 is absolutely right about span/div and display inline/block, but on a side note I'd add that what you're trying to achieve is often done with a list (as it really is a list of links in your footer)

```
<ul class="footer">
  <li class="no-print">KnowledgeBase</li>
    ...
  <li>888-888-888</li>
<ul>
```

with a css like

```
.footer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;    
}

.footer li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}​
```

hope that helps

Comment: I agree and upvote, but there's a touch of "CSS overkill" here. It's just a silly footer line, no need to be so smart.

Comment: Thanks to your upvote I can finally comment (and that's what I'd have done on your answer, but since I couldn't I felt like giving a full example was more answer-like)

Answer (score 4):

Use `<span>`.

However you can make a div "inline" using the style `display: inline`, but in this case you just need a `<span>`.

Comment: Thank you gd1 for your help.  I'll try using the span, and putting the class "semismallcontent" in div tags.  If that doesn't work, I'll try the display: inline, although I don't know how to program stylesheets.  IF you see this, I added to my post by including what I have on my print.css stylesheet.  Thank you again for taking the time to read, respond, and help me out; I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks :)
Just an hint: try not to name you CSS classes after what they appear, name it after what they are, if possible. If you call the footer div "semismallcontent" then you'll have to change it if you want to make the footer 1pt bigger (but not all the other "semismallcontent" stuff). Do a "footer" class, instead...

Answer (score 2):

use css

```
<div style="display:inline" class="noprint">whatever I want omitted when printing </div>
```

If not use the inline counterpart span, as a answer already said. But remember inline display donot have block properties like height, top-margin, bottom-margin.

Comment: Thank you Rohit.  I never realized how important it is to specify the width and height in your css.  I'll be hitting w3schools to learn more about the display:inline property.  Thank you again for your the information!

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use an extra div, I recommend using display:inline, but if you just want the whole footer to have both classes you can do that as well.

You can add multiple classes like this:

```
<span class='footer lower noprint'></span>
```

In CSS this would look like:

```
.footer.lower.noprint{ display:none; }
```

Alternatively, the 'noprint' class will also work without specifying all three classes.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yKRyp/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make a fiddle for me -- playing around with the fiddle really helped me learn more about how the various css properties work.  I appreciate your help, and the information!

Comment: You're Welcome! :)  I'm happy to have provided useful information that helped you learn the CSS attributes!

Answer (score 1):

well set the specific `width` and `height` of the `div` using CSS and apply `float`

```
<div style='float:left; border:1px solid blue; width:100px; height:100px'>
div 1
</div>
<div style='float:left; border:1px solid red; width:100px; height:100px'>
div 2
</div><div style='float:left; border:1px solid orange; width:100px; height:100px'>
div 3
</div>
```

a live example here

http://jsfiddle.net/AGWGs/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, Mahan.  I'm working on the print.css, although I don't know too much about how to program css's.  But thank you for responding, as you set me on the right track!

Comment: you're welcome =) well you must bring yourself to CSS soon =) goodluck

Comment: Yes, and thank you for the fiddle, also ... that really helped.  I didn't realize how important it was to set the proper widths ... This is the closest I've come to getting what I'd like to get.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`div` is a block-type element, it is usually used as to group and contain block-type elements.
Using CSS, you can change the display type of any element, however.

In a quick example:

`display:inline` Makes an element to show inline, they can be put side by side. `span` element is an inline element. This cannot use block-type-only css rules such as: `margin`, `padding`, `width`, `height` ...

`display:block` Makes an element to be displayed as a block. Unless inherited values or given CSS rules, they will take a line long, blocked. They can take block-type CSS rules. And they can be stacked side-by-side using `float`. However, unless the line is cleared(`clear: left`, `clear:right` or `clear:both`), following elements after the floated element will overflow the previous container.

`display:inline-block` Makes an element have block features, with inline displaying. This is pretty similiar to using `float` and making block-type elements shown in-line. However this rule is IE8+ support only, so I would encourage you to use floating to keep the maximum compatibility.

`P.S: There are hacks that can be used to have display:inline-block feature used on IE5.5+.`

Comment: Thank you for the information, deadlike!  I really have to learn more about float:left, display:inline, but I'm getting there!  I appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Comment: You're welcome. If you're new to CSS I encourage you to take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/ that's where you'll get to experiment and learn! ^^